# CodeIgniter-controller not found

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to get a variable with ajax from href to the controller, which get this variable and send the output to a div. The problem that I am having is that it doesn't find the path.

This is how i pass the variable to controller "content" in function loadpage().

```
<a href="'.base_url().'content/load_page?id='.$value['id'].'">'.$value['title'].'</a>
```

This are the functions at my controller

```
public function index(){
  $content = $this->load_page();
  $this->load->view('index',array('data'=>$content));
 }

 public function load_page() {
  $id=$this->input->get('id');
  $data['content']= $this->ug_model->get_content($id);
  return json_encode($data);
 }
```

Ajax

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

 $('#documenter_nav li a').click(function(){
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  alert(url);

  $.get( url,function(data){
  $('div#content').html(data.content);
  });
 });
```

I am using two controllers and content is not my default controller.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that u use get, so you should use parameters in your PHP code like this:

```
public function load_page($id) {
    $data['content']= $this->ug_model->get_content($id);
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: so what should i pass at href ? how should be the path?

Comment: it does not matter how you take parameter using get or with function. both work same

Comment: the ajax call doesn't work because it redirects to another page

Comment: Just debug your ajax code, and see what value the url contains

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `site_url()` instead of `base_url()`.

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('content/load_page?id'.$value['id'])?>"><?php echo $value['title'];?></a>
```

Comment: now the problem is with ajax, it redirects me to another page. what may be th e problem?